# Windows 7 recycle bin is damaged after an abrupt drop in electric current

Tags: windows-7, hardware-failure

I always use an inverter when using my computer, but it does not support any abrupt break in electric current. So my computer—running Windows 7 Integral Edition—suddenly powered off. Then when I started my computer then I got this error:

[image]

My disk have two partitions: `C:` and `D:`.

So how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hidden folder in the root of your `D:` drive that you want to delete. To do so, open an elevated command prompt by tapping the `Windows Key`, type in `cmd`, hold `ctrl`+`shift` and press enter. Accept the UAC prompt that comes up and you'll have an administrator command prompt. Type:

`RD /S /Q D:\$Recycle.bin`

Make sure that you type it exactly as you see here. Press enter, wait for the command to finish (it might be instant) and close the command prompt. You can then restart the computer. The folder will be recreated and the problem will be solved.

Comment: And then Windows creates a new one?